# Wireshark Plugin: Is There a non-ntoh Version of tvb_get_ntoh64?

Tags: c++, endianness, wireshark

I am writing a Wireshark dissector plugin for a protocol that does not `hton` it's data, and I need to extract a 64-bit data value without doing any endian conversions.

Is there a version of `tvb_get_ntoh64` included in the Wireshark libraries that does not do the `ntoh`?

Comment: Can't you just `hton` the resulting data ? That's an ugly hack but I also can't see why a decent protocol would represent data in some host specific byte order format.

Comment: I could, sure, but would rather not if there's a way round that.  Agree with you regarding the decentness of this protocol - it is something I opposed when the protocol was designed.  Alas, I lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.  The wireshark document \wireshark\doc\README.developer addresses this:

> Don't fetch a little-endian value
>   using "tvb_get_ntohs() or
>   "tvb_get_ntohl()" and then using
>   "g_ntohs()", "g_htons()", "g_ntohl()",
>   or "g_htonl()" on the resulting value
>   - the g_ routines in question convert between network byte order
>   (big-endian) and *host* byte order,
>   not *little-endian* byte order; not
>   all machines on which Wireshark runs
>   are little-endian, even though PCs
>   are.  Fetch those values using
>   "tvb_get_letohs()" and
>   "tvb_get_letohl()".

In looking in `tvbuff.h`, I see there are other flavors as well:

```
extern guint16 tvb_get_letohs(tvbuff_t*, const gint offset);
extern guint32 tvb_get_letoh24(tvbuff_t*, const gint offset);
extern guint32 tvb_get_letohl(tvbuff_t*, const gint offset);
extern guint64 tvb_get_letoh64(tvbuff_t*, const gint offset);
```

Posting so that people asking this question in the future will be able to find the answer.